# Visualforce : Dynamic rendering of apex:inputfield

Tags: apex, visualforce, dynamic-visualforce

I have a custom object `Response__c` as shown below.

[image]

xx,yy,zz are different field values for the three records.

Please note that not all fields are populated for all the three records.

**A single apex:inputfield is to be shown in the VF Page whose "value" property will be determined at runtime**

I followed an earlier post's advice

[VF component dynamic inputField](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/64881/vf-component-dynamic-inputfield)

and refactored my code as below

**Component markup**

```
<apex:component controller="DynamicApexController" >
    <apex:attribute name="inputObject" type="sObject" description="Object Name"/>
    <apex:attribute name="inputFieldName" type="String" description="Field Name"/>
    <apex:inputField value="{!r[inputFieldName]}"/>
</apex:component>
```

**Component controller**

```
public with sharing class DynamicApexController {

public Response__c r {get;set;}
public Response__c getr()
{

Response__c newr = new Response__c();
return newr;

}



}
```

**Visualforce Page**

```
<!-- Page: -->

<apex:page >
<apex:form >

    <c:myComponent1 myValue="My composents value" borderColor="green" /> 
    <c:dynamicinput inputFieldName="Field1__c"  id="first" rendered="true" />
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

But I am getting the following error when navigating to the VF Page.
Attached is the error screenshot below.

Can someone let me know what is wrong ?

**Error Screenshot**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this - [VF component dynamic inputField](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/64881/vf-component-dynamic-inputfield).

I think you should replace r with attribute inputobject and pass the inputobject parameter from VF to even make sobject dynamic.

Thanks,
Abhishek